# How do i test all variations?

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a program that will tell me all possible ties in the electoral college (swing states only). I considered that all non-swing states would be how the normally vote (red 201, blue 164).

So what i have now is a HashMap states that has the state names as keys and their respective vote amounts as values.

How would I go about writing a recursive method that would test every possibility, and when there is a tie, print out a list of which states voted red and which states voted blue.

I just need someone to guide me on how to tackle this issue. I simply don't know where to start. This is pretty much all i have so far:

```
public class ElectoralCollege {

private HashMap<String, Integer> states;
private int red;
private int blue;
private ArrayList<String> redStates;
private ArrayList<String> blueStates;

public ElectoralCollege(){
    states = new HashMap<>();        
    loadStates();
    setDefaultVotes();
}

private void loadStates(){
    states.put("Florida", 29);
    states.put("Pennsylvania", 20);
    states.put("Ohio", 18);
    states.put("Georgia",16);
    states.put("Michigan",16);
    states.put("North Carolina",15);
    states.put("Virginia", 13);
    states.put("Arizona", 11);
    states.put("Wisconsin",10);
    states.put("Colorado",9);
    states.put("Nevada",6);
    states.put("Iowa",6);
    states.put("New Hampshire", 4);   
}

private void setDefaultVotes(){
    red = 201;
    blue = 164;
}

public void printTies(){
    if(red == 269 && blue == 269){
        System.out.println("Red: " + redStates);
        System.out.println("Blue: " + blueStates);
    }

    //Implement the part that makes each state blue and makes each state red?

    if(red < 269 && blue < 269)
        printTies();
}
```

Comment: The problem simplifies to this: with the given array of electoral vote counts outstanding, you need to find all the combinations that add up to 269-201 (a tie, as seen from the red candidate).  Search StackOverflow for how to find combinations that sum to a given value -- this has been solved several times in that past few months.

Comment: the first thing to consider when writing a recursive function is when do you know you are done?

Comment: Aren't you a little late ?? :)